# ggplot2, x-axis does not display ticks accurately

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m creating a barplot for my poster and have run into an issue.
I have a factor on my x axis, and a numeric on my y axis. I want my x axis to display every level of my factor, but with a differerent name.

To do that, I used the scale_x_discrete command, which is supposed to allow me to do that. However, it just deletes all ticks. Please find below all the code required to reproduce the problem.

```
F_Value <- c(13.011, 8.827, 15.586, 7.223, 16.190, 9.844)
Pathway <- as.factor(1:6)
Transformation <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
Outlier <- as.factor(c("Outliers", "Outlier Removed",
                       "Outliers", "Outlier Removed",
                       "Outliers", "Outlier Removed"))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(F_Value, Pathway, Transformation, Outlier))
df


ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = Pathway, 
           y = F_Value, f
           ill = factor(Outlier))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "Raw", "2" = "Raw, Trimmed", 
                              "3" = "Log", "4" = "Log, Trimmed", 
                              "5" = "Normalised", "6" = "Normalised, Trimmed")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Outliers", 
                      labels = c("Trimmed", "Not Trimmed")) +
  xlab("Pathway") +
  ylab("F-Statistic") +
  ggtitle("F-Statistics by Pathway") +
  theme_light()
```

Comment: Your cbind statement is converting your factors into numeric variables.  To define df just use: `df <-data.frame(F_Value, Pathway, Transformation, Outlier)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your x variable to character:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = as.character(Pathway), 
           y = F_Value, f
           ill = factor(Outlier))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "Raw", "2" = "Raw, Trimmed", 
                              "3" = "Log", "4" = "Log, Trimmed", 
                              "5" = "Normalised", "6" = "Normalised, Trimmed")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Outliers", 
                      labels = c("Trimmed", "Not Trimmed")) +
  xlab("Pathway") +
  ylab("F-Statistic") +
  ggtitle("F-Statistics by Pathway") +
  theme_light()
```